# Website table not showing up when accessing with python Mechanize, how do I find it?

Tags: python, html, mechanize

So I'm trying to make a web scraper to look up the status of a class on my schools online registration page. I have gotten to the page where it lists all the info about the class, I'm looking for how many seats are open. The HTML I'm getting from Mechanize doesn't include the table, I think it is because the table is put there with a non-html call.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/13c459a04fcf80ecff63
This is the what I get when I view the page source. You can see near the bottom that there is a waitlist and that it is full (line 47).

This is my mechanize output:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6acde9061e0d11b43cc
It doesn't have the table which should have started after the last line. If anyone needs the full html I'll post another gist of it.

I've heard that Spidermonkey can help with these issues or beautifulsoup?

edit: here is full html from page source

```html
!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/transitional.dtd">
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" NAME="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" NAME="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="https://my.sandiego.edu/sandiego/includes/course_search.css" TYPE="text/css">
<LINK REL="stylesheet" HREF="/css/web_defaultprint.css" TYPE="text/css" media="print">
<TITLE>USD Course Search</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Script-Type" NAME="Default_Script_Language" CONTENT="text/javascript">
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers 
var submitcount=0;
function checkSubmit() {
if (submitcount == 0)
   {
   submitcount++;
   return true;
   }
else
   {
alert("Your changes have already been submitted.");
   return false;
   }
}
//  End script hiding -->
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide JavaScript from older browsers 
//  Function to open a window
function windowOpen(window_url) {
   helpWin = window.open(window_url,'','toolbar=yes,status=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no,width=350,height=400');
   if (document.images) { 
       if (helpWin) helpWin.focus()
   }
}
//  End script hiding -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div id="headerImage">
<IMG SRC="/wtlgifs/H_logo.gif" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE=""  NAME="USD Header" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=69 WIDTH=321>
</div>
<DIV class="headerwrapperdiv">
<DIV class="pageheaderdiv1">
<A HREF="#main_content" onMouseover="window.status='Go to Main Content'; return true" onMouseout="window.status=''; return true" OnFocus="window.status='Go to Main Content'; return true" onBlur="window.status=''; return true" class="skiplinks">Go to Main Content</A>
<H1>University of San Diego Faculty/Student Self-Service System</H1></DIV><DIV class="headerlinksdiv">
</DIV>
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This table displays Menu Items and Banner Search textbox."
         WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<DIV class="headerlinksdiv2">
<FORM ACTION="/prod/twbksrch.P_ShowResults" METHOD="POST">
Search
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltextinvisible"><LABEL for=keyword_in_id><SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Search</SPAN></LABEL></SPAN>
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="KEYWRD_IN" SIZE="20" MAXLENGTH="65" ID="keyword_in_id">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Go">
</FORM>
</div>
</TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"><p class="rightaligntext"></p>
<SPAN class="pageheaderlinks">
<A HREF="/prod/twbksite.P_DispSiteMap?menu_name_in=bmenu.P_MainMnu&amp;depth_in=2&amp;columns_in=3" accesskey="2" class="submenulinktext2">SITE MAP</A>
|
<A HREF="/wtlhelp/twbhhelp.htm" accesskey="H" onClick="popup = window.open('/wtlhelp/twbhhelp.htm', 'PopupPage','height=500,width=450,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes'); return false" target="_blank" onMouseOver="window.status='';  return true" onMouseOut="window.status=''; return true"onFocus="window.status='';  return true" onBlur="window.status=''; return true"  class="submenulinktext2">HELP</A>
|
<A HREF="twbkwbis.P_Logout" accesskey="3" class="submenulinktext2">EXIT</A>
</span>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
</DIV>
<DIV class="pagetitlediv">
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This table displays title and static header displays."
   WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
<H2>USD Course Search</H2>
</TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault">
&nbsp;
</TD>
<TD CLASS="pldefault"><p class="rightaligntext"></p>
<DIV class="staticheaders">
</div>
</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD class="bg3" width="100%" colSpan=3><IMG SRC="/wtlgifs/web_transparent.gif" ALT="Transparent Image" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="Transparent Image"  NAME="web_transparent" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=3 WIDTH=10></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
<a name="main_content"></a>
</DIV>
<DIV class="pagebodydiv">
<!--  ** END OF twbkwbis.P_OpenDoc **  -->
<DIV class="infotextdiv"><TABLE  CLASS="infotexttable" SUMMARY="This layout table contains information that may be helpful in understanding the content and functionality of this page.  It could be a brief set of instructions, a description of error messages, or other special information."><TR><TD CLASS="indefault"><IMG SRC="/wtlgifs/twgginfo.gif" ALT="Information" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="Information"  NAME="Info" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=24 WIDTH=27></TD><TD CLASS="indefault"><SPAN class="infotext"> <font color=red>Please do not use the back button on your web browser to return to the course search page.  Use the link provided in order to return to the course search page.</font> Please refine your search by searching by department or other field.  If the search results are too large you will see an error when you try to add a class.</SPAN></TD></TR></TABLE><P></DIV>
<style>
#course-query h3{
  margin: 10px 0 5px 0;
}
#course-query fieldset{
  border: 1px dotted #eee;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
#course-query legend{
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#course-query legend span{
  font-weight: normal;
}
#course-query .week{
  font-size: 1.0em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#course-query .week td{
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#course-query .week th{
  font-size: 0.9em;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#course-query label.sub-label {
  color: #666;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
#course-query .registration-status{
  color: #666;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;
  font-size:0.9em;
}
#course-query .course-blocks .registration-status{
  font-size:0.8em;
}

.course-query{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.course-query label{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 9.5em;
}

.course-query label em{
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.course-query label.top{
    float:none;
    width:auto;
}

.course-query li{
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.course-query li.buttons{
    background: #f4f4f4;
    padding: 10px;
}

.course-query li em{
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
#course-query-results{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
#course-query-results ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#course-query-results label{
    float: left;
    width: 10em;
}
#course-query-results li{
    clear: both;
    list-style: none;
}
#course-query-results li li{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
#course-query-results .closed{
    color:#AC0B0B;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#course-query-results .commands{
    margin: 5px 10px; 
}
#course-query-results .course{
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 5px 10px; 
    padding: 5px;
}
#course-query-results h2{
    color: #85360F;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#course-query-results .instructors{
    float: right;
}
#course-query-results td{padding: 3px;}
#course-query-results th{padding: 3px;}
#course-query-results .alt{color: #666;}
#course-query-results tr.alt{background-color: #f4f4f4;color:black;}
#course-query-results .instructors label{display:none;}
#course-query-results .details label{display: none;}
#course-query-results .course .attributes{}
#course-query-results .course .credits{}
#course-query-results .course .meeting{border-top:1px solid #eee;}
#course-query-results .course .description{border-top:1px solid #ddd; padding:3px;}
#course-query-results .course .seats{}
#course-query-results .course strong{color:#000;}
#course-query-results .course table{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#course-query-results .course .title{
    color:#008000; 
    font-size:1.1em; 
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#course-query-results #courses{padding:0px;}
#course-query-results .red_title{color:#AC0B0B;}
</style>
<div id="course-query">
<div style="font-size:0.9em;">
[ 
<a href="usd_course_query.p_create?pv_termcode=201502&pv_termcode2=&pv_source=">create a new query for 201502</a>
] 
</div>
<TABLE  CLASS="datadisplaytable" id="course-query-results" summary="This table displays students from a student query."><CAPTION class="captiontext">Query Results</CAPTION>
<TR>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >CRN:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Course<br/>Number:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Course<br/>Section:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Title:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Textbook<br/>Information:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Course<br/>Requirements:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Fee:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Credits:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Start<br/>Date:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >End<br/>Date:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Begin<br/>Time:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >End<br/>Time:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Seats<br/>Remaining:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Reserved<br/>Seats:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Instructors:</TH>
<TH CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Location:</TH>
</TR>
<TR class="alt ">
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">2839</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">PHIL-332</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">01</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
Business Ethics</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault"><a href="http://usd-pc.verbasoftware.com/express?remote=1&ref=5380&term=USD+SPRING+2015&dept=PHIL&course=332&section=01&getbooks=display+books" target="_blank">Click Here</a></TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">P</TD>
<TD CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault"align="center">3</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
TR</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
26-JAN-15</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
11-MAY-15</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
7:45 am</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
9:05 am</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault"><em style="font-color:red;">CLOSED(Waitlist Full)</em></TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
Matt  Zwolinski
</TD>
<TD NOWRAP CLASS="dddefault">
MH205</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
Your query returned 1 records.
<div style="font-size:0.9em;">
[ 
<a href="usd_course_query.p_create?pv_termcode=201502&pv_termcode2=">create a new query for 201502</a>
] 
</div>
</div>

<!--  ** START OF twbkwbis.P_CloseDoc **  -->
<TABLE  CLASS="plaintable" SUMMARY="This is table displays line separator at end of the page."
                                             WIDTH="100%" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 border=0><TR><TD class="bgtabon" width="100%" colSpan=2><IMG SRC="/wtlgifs/web_transparent.gif" ALT="Transparent Image" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="Transparent Image"  NAME="web_transparent" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=3 WIDTH=10></TD></TR></TABLE>
<A HREF="#top" onMouseover="window.status='Skip to top of page'; return true" onMouseout="window.status=''; return true" OnFocus="window.status='Skip to top of page'; return true" onBlur="window.status=''; return true" class="skiplinks">Skip to top of page</A>
</DIV>
<DIV class="footerbeforediv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="footerafterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="globalafterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="globalfooterdiv">

</DIV>
<DIV class="pagefooterdiv">
<SPAN class="releasetext">Release: 7.3</SPAN>
</DIV>
<DIV class="poweredbydiv">
</DIV>
<DIV class="div1"></DIV>
<DIV class="div2"></DIV>
<DIV class="div3"></DIV>
<DIV class="div4"></DIV>
<DIV class="div5"></DIV>
<DIV class="div6"></DIV>
<div class="banner_copyright"> <br><h5>© 2014 Ellucian Company L.P. and its affiliates.<br></h5></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Yeah, post the full HTML. I suspect there's some jQuery calls that are happening and making it difficult (if not impossible) for `Mechanize` to 'see' the table.

Comment: added html from view page-source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an AJAX issue. Mechanize can't render javascript. I would recommend using Selenium WebDriver + PhantomJS.

Comment: How would I use those? I have the url and can request the webpage

Answer (score 0):

It's a javascript thing. Those tables aren't created with the rest of the html, they're created later. Mechanize, as far as I know, doesn't really have the ability to grab that data so you'll be waiting forever. As suggested, you could try to do this with [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), I've worked with them before and found them pretty straight forward to use.

TL;DR: Your current strategy isn't going to be implemented easily (if at all). You're going to need to use something other than `Mechanize`.